# Google Audiences call - Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Having issues with this call for google audiences:

Request URL:`https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-55555566-15&cid=1275559405.1499555197&jid=1255555157&_v=j60&z=117765965`

Returns 400 Bad Request error. Not sure what the exact issue is. This call is not something you place on your website directly as I don't see it in my page source at all, so I think it is dynamically called based on the standard Google Analytics code you place on your site and if you have audience definitions created in your Analytics account. Hence, it doesn't seem like something I have control over on how the request is formed/made.

Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```